# Error in pop * mx : non-comformable arrays?

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the Lee-Carter function call in R for mortality rates, but I keep getting this "Error in pop * mx : non-conformable arrays" message when I try to make the call.

I have the demogdata already stored (I know I don't have a range of ages for the ages argument for demogdata(), but I just want to find the overall mortality rate for the subset of the population I'm looking at).

```
> (xyz = demogdata(Rates, Pop, ages = mean(data$AGE), years = 2006:2014, 
   type = "mortality", label = "US", name = "total"))
Mortality data for US
Series: total
Years: 2006 - 2014
Ages:  28.9763585116791 - 28.9763585116791
```

All of the variables I have are as follows:

```
> Rates
            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
[1,] 0.002540197 0.002242095 0.001958826 0.001708285 0.001434417
            [,6]         [,7]         [,8]         [,9]
[1,] 0.001218796 0.0009218339 0.0006424075 0.0003361666


> years
[1] 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014

> Pop
       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]    [,6]    [,7]    [,8]    [,9]
[1,] 179120 352795 516636 682556 851217 1012475 1180256 1343384 1493307

> (ages <- mean(data$AGE))
 [1] 28.97636
```

Here are my input arguments to the lca() function call

```
out <- lca(xyz, years = c(2006:2014), ages = mean(all.mod2014$AGE), 
             adjust="dt", restype = "rates")
Error in pop * mx : non-conformable arrays
```

Comment: Don't you see this as strange: `Ages:  28.9763585116791 - 28.9763585116791` How is the LCA method supposed to do anything with that?